# nginx 500 error, permission denied for tmp folder

Tags: django, nginx, permissions

I got 500 from Django admin, when I tried to upload a photo.

When I inspect the error.log I found:

```
2014/03/13 23:00:55 [crit] 16478#0: *24 open() "/var/lib/nginx/tmp/client_body/0000000012" failed (13: Permission denied), client: xxxxxxx.xxx, server: xxxxxxx.xxx, request: "POST xxxxxxx.xxx/item/86/ HTTP/1.1", host: "xxxxxxx.xxx", referrer: "http://xxxxxxx.xxx/item/86/"
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What could be wrong here?

Comment: If you are using django >= 1.5, try setting the `ALLOWED_HOSTS`

Comment: @karthikr Thanks! It's already set as the server's ip. If I edit the text, everything work. Only uploading photo gives 500.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69504680/5117552

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Phew. Solved. As the error message says, this indeed was just a "Permission" issue.

Check through "/var/lib/nginx/tmp/client_body/" and make sure the permission is correct at each directory level solve the issue.

More details can be found here : http://derekneely.com/2009/06/nginx-failed-13-permission-denied-while-reading-upstream/  and here : [Permission Denied error with Django while uploading a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682440/permission-denied-error-with-django-while-uploading-a-file?rq=1)

Comment: does restarting django recreate the issue? or was it a one time thing ?

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady Hi. I don't quite understand your question. Restarting Django made no difference in my case.

Comment: was just asking if the permission issue was a one time thing or was it being reproduced with each django restart

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady It's one time thing.