# Media uploads django mezzanine giving HTTP Error 500

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, mezzanine

I'm trying to setup `django` and the cms package `mezzanine` to use `amazon s3` storage using `django-storages`  and `django-s3-folder-storage`. All works well in the sense that I can use `collectstatic` without issue and upload my files to amazon, and also images get served correctly as does css/js.

However if a user tries to upload an image to the `media-library` or as a `featured-image` for a blog post. I get simply `HTTP Error` in the browser and `POST /admin/media-library/upload_file/ HTTP/1.1" 500 146580` in the console. This is with `DEBUG=True` set, so I'm surprised there is not more of a trace/feedback.

I'm not sure what to do to fix or even begin debugging why this is occurring, anyone help?

My relevant settings.py are:

```
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'my_bucket'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'my_key'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'my_id'

AWS_PRELOAD_METADATA = True 
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
AWS_S3_SECURE_URLS = False
AWS_S3_ENCRYPTION =  False
from boto.s3.connection import ProtocolIndependentOrdinaryCallingFormat
AWS_S3_CALLING_FORMAT = ProtocolIndependentOrdinaryCallingFormat()

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 's3_folder_storage.s3.DefaultStorage'
DEFAULT_S3_PATH = "media"
MEDIA_ROOT = ''
MEDIA_URL = ''

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 's3_folder_storage.s3.StaticStorage'
STATIC_S3_PATH = "static"
STATIC_ROOT = "/%s/" % STATIC_S3_PATH
STATIC_URL = '//s3.amazonaws.com/%s/static/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = STATIC_URL + 'admin/'
```

Comment: Have you managed to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. What the problem turned out to be for me was in my setup I needed to change the permissions on this directory (and all its sub-directories) to be owned by the user used by my `nginx.conf`:

`/var/lib/nginx`

To correct this I did:

`sudo chown -R <myuser>:<myuser> /var/lib/nginx`

Where myuser is the nginx user specified in `nginx.conf`.

Think images you are uploading are placed in a temporary folder in there before reaching Amazon S3 and this temporary folder doesn't have the correct permissions to allow this.

What got me on the right track to fix this was I changed debug to `DEBUG = True` and then when I got the 500 error in my error logs I saw:

`[crit] 26489#0: *374 open() "/var/lib/nginx/tmp/client_body/0000000050" failed (13: Permission denied),`

Also have a look at this:

[nginx 500 error, permission denied for tmp folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22382889/nginx-500-error-permission-denied-for-tmp-folder)