# Unable to remote deploy on Tomcat through Nginx reverse proxy

Tags: java, tomcat, nginx, deployment

Installed a tomcat environment on my test server (Fedora 26). Everything is stock package. I've also installed and setup Nginx reverse proxy on the front. `tomcat-users.xml` is set and I can login to the app manager as expected.

Now, when I try to deploy a WAR to it, I get critical failure on my Nginx log:

```
2017/09/25 15:12:21 [crit] 13878#0: *36 open() "/var/lib/nginx/tmp/client_body/000000XXXX" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 200.x.x.x, server: some-sandbox.com, request: "POST /manager/html/upload?org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=XXXXXXXxxxx HTTP/1.1", host: "some-sandbox.com", referrer: "https://some-sandbox.com/manager/html/upload?org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=XXXXXXXxxxx
```

Nginx then return 500 internal server to browser.

What could I have get wrong? Any suggestion how to tackle?

Thanks.

Comment: probably because of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22382889/nginx-500-error-permission-denied-for-tmp-folder

Comment: Please post nginx.conf and server.xml

Comment: You can check the user privilage on the file for current user.

Comment: @Oleg I've check `/var/lib/nginx/tmp` and its owned by `apache` (the nginx user). Any more suggestion(s)?

Comment: And what about tomcat? The deployment is done by tomcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is some permission issue with the temporary upload folder `/var/lib/nginx/tmp`. I've made sure that the whole path is owned by the correct system user. But the issue still exists.

So to circumvent the issue, I decided to config Nginx to skip caching the client body at all. For my purpose, there is no practically value to cache before proxying.

Nginx 1.7.11 introduced a new [proxy_request_buffering](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_request_buffering) directive. If you set it to `off`, the buffering would be disabled. And hence any permission issue would not affect the upload.

So my server section has this:

```
location / {
    proxy_request_buffering off;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can check the user privilage on the file for current user.

Comment: This should be a comment and not an answer

Comment: As stated in comment above, the folder `/var/lib/nginx/tmp` is owned by the appropriate user.