# Django save file on localhost

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm working on a Django app (DRF), but I'm a JS engineer so this is all new to me.

I have this in my models.py, outside of any actual models:

```
storage = S3Storage(aws_s3_bucket_name=settings.DOCUMENTS_BUCKET)
upload_location = 'recordings/'
```

and this is a field it is used in, inside one of the models:

```
zip_file = models.FileField(
    upload_to=upload_location, storage=storage, null=True)
```

This works OK in production. However, I want to be able to test it locally, add those zip files when developing locally. So I've added this for `storage` and `upload_location`:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
  storage = FileSystemStorage(location='/')
  upload_location = ''
```

Then, when I try saving a file from admin on localhost, I get the following error:

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/my-file.zip'
```

If I got it right, the app cannot just create that location somewhere on my file system. Maybe I'm wrong. How can I solve this?

Comment: Have  you checked the folder permissions? If not, set the folder permissions to allow file creation...

Comment: Since this is file system storage, `/` refers to the root directly of your filesystem. Are you sure that's where you want to store things? Surely `MEDIA_ROOT` would be a better place.

Comment: Check out the answer on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682440/permission-denied-error-with-django-while-uploading-a-file

Comment: @DanielRoseman for some reason, I thought `/` refers to the root of the project that's currently running and I've changed those permissions. Modified the path now and it's fine.Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locations passed into `FileField` are relative to the `MEDIA_ROOT` unless it starts with a slash. If it starts with a slash, this is an absolute path and is relative to the root of your drive.

So, `location='/'` means the root of your hard drive (hence the permissions issues.)

You can use `./` to use the `MEDIA_ROOT`, but it's normally best to group your assets based on some criteria. For example, for a model called `SomeModel`, place the assets somewhere like `location='some-models/'`.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you take a look at [django-storages](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).
You can save files on models easily using FileSystem for localhost and S3 for production.
All configurations are gonna be on settings, so you wouldn't need to put IFs anymore.